# Draw grid lines on specific values in xyplot

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have a `xyplot` and I want to draw grid lines on the 0 values.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using package `lattice` (which is implied with `xyplot`), you can use `panel.abline` to draw lines over labeled ticks.

```
my.df <- data.frame(a = runif(10, min = -1, max = 1), b = runif(10, min = -1, max = 1))
my.plot <- xyplot(b ~ a, data = my.df)
update(my.plot, panel = function(...) {
            panel.abline(h = 0, v = 0, lty = "dotted", col = "light grey")
            panel.xyplot(...)
        })
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

According to [lattice changelog](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/NEWS):

> Changes in lattice 0.19
>   =======================
>
> o Added new arguments `'grid'` and `'abline'` in `panel.xyplot()`.

So you could do it in one line:

```
require(lattice)
X <- data.frame(xx=runif(20), yy=rnorm(20))

xyplot(yy~xx, X, abline=list(h=0))
```

[image: Lattice graph with added line]

If you want `panel.grid` like line style, then nice trick:

```
xyplot(yy~xx, X, abline=c(list(h=0),trellis.par.get("reference.line")))
```

[image: Lattice graph with added nice style line]

Answer (score 1):

There is a lattice llines function that replaces the function of lines() functionality in base. There is also a panel.lines function.

```
#---------- method --------------
 xyplot(-1:1 ~ -1:1, type="l")
trellis.focus("panel", 1, 1)
do.call("panel.abline", list(h=0,v=0, lty=3) )
trellis.unfocus()
# --- that method has the advantage of also demonstrating 
#        how to modify an existing plot

#---------- method 2--------------

 xp <-xyplot(-2:1 ~ -2:1, type="l", panel=function(...){
 panel.xyplot(...)
 panel.abline(h=0,v=0, lty=3)} )
xp
```

Comment: can you give me an example please