# how to add a general grid to a lattice xy.plot

Tags: r, lattice

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008863/draw-grid-lines-on-specific-values-in-xyplot) question explains how to add grids at specific
points for a lattice plot (i.e. the equivalent of
two abline()'s for a normal plot). My problem is that when
i try to add a regular grid (the equivalent of a call to grid()
for a normal plot)...the content of the plots... disappear. Here is an example:

```
B<-cbind(rnorm(100),rnorm(100), floor(runif(100,1,7)), floor(runif(100,1,3)), 
           floor(runif(100,1,4)))
colnames(B)<-c("yval","xval","gval","p","cr")
B<-as.data.frame(B)
xyplot(B$yval~B$xval|B$p*B$cr,group=B$gval,main="Scatterplots by Cylinders and Gears", 
           ylab="Miles per Gallon", xlab="Car Weight",type="l",lwd=5,
           panel=function(x,y){panel.grid()})
```

if you remove the last option (i.e. panel=function(x,y){panel.grid()}) then i see the data-lines, but not the grid(). Is there a way to have *both* the grid and the data-lines

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
xyplot(yval ~ xval | p*cr, data=B, group=gval, type=c("l","g"), lwd=5, 
       main="Scatterplots by Cylinders and Gears",
       ylab="Miles per Gallon", xlab="Car Weight")
```

I have simplified a little bit your syntax because you can use variable names from you data.frame if you the `data=` argument. The key is to use `type=c("l","g")`, which means lines + grid, and is equivalent to a panel function that would looks like

```
panel=function(...) {
  panel.xyplot(...)
  panel.grid()
}
```

In your case, this is because you forgot to add a `panel.xyplot()` that no points or line were drawn.
If you want a different grid, you can use the above code and customize the call to `panel.grid()`.

Comment: @user189035 See `help(panel.grid)`: there's a `col=` argument. You'll need to use a custom panel function like the one above, because `col.line=` cannot be passed directly to `xyplot` without interfering with the `group=` argument. You'll likely end up with something like `panel.grid(h=-1, v=-1, col.line="red")`.